# Why Firefox is working perfectly well on Ubuntu, and not on Windows?

Tags: windows, firefox

When I use Firefox 7.0.1 on Ubuntu it is working great and fast, however on Windows it is amazingly slow.

Does anyone have any suggestions why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Firefox 4, it can use hardware acceleration to speed up page rendering. I'm wondering if something is wrong with your Windows set-up so Firefox can't use that or maybe it is trying to use acceleration but for some reason it is *slower* then non-accelerated rendering. Are you by any chance using generic VGA drivers in Windows?

Here's [how to tell if Firefox uses hardware acceleration](http://blog.mozilla.com/joe/2010/11/10/how-to-tell-if-youre-using-hardware-acceleration/)

But really, the question does not belong here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firefox 7.0.1 on Vista, and it seems to work pretty well.  The only problem I have (new with 7.0.1) is that it doesn't render Apple's iOs reference pages correctly.